# Как передать список объектов на бэк через ajax в формате application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, java, spring, url

На фронте есть такой список

```
[
    {
       treatmentType: 'ONE_TIME',
       nickname: 'qwerty',
       active: true
    },
    {
       treatmentType: 'RECURRING',
       nickname: 'ytrewq',
       active: false
    }
]
```

на бэке спринг контроллер

```
public InfoForm getDetails(@Valid InfoForm form)
```

форма

```
public class InfoForm{

    List<TreatmentEntity> entities;

    public static class TreatmentEntity {

        TreatmentType treatmentType;
        String nickname;
        boolean active;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решениде которое подошло мне

```
httpf.ajaxPost('/info', {
      'entities[0].treatmentType':front_entities[0].treatmentType,
      'entities[0].nickname'     :front_entities[0].nickname,
      'entities[0].active'       :front_entities[0].active,                
      'entities[1].treatmentType':front_entities[1].treatmentType,
      'entities[1].nickname'     :front_entities[1].nickname,
      'entities[1].active'       :front_entities[1].active
}).then(function (data) {
      location.reload();
}, function (data) {
      console.log(data.errors)
});
```